# How to create a folder in python

Tags: python-3.x, glob

Please, what is wrong in my code. I did the same thing elsewhere and it worked.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import os, re
from IPython import get_ipython
import shutil
get_ipython().magic('reset -sf')
os.system('cls||clear')
Path_th = "I:/White_Bubble_2023/COSMIC_Unzipped/"
os.chdir(Path_th)
files = glob(Path_th + "*_nc", recursive = True)
Path_save = "I:/White_Bubble_2023/COSMIC_Renamed/"
for i in range(len(files)):
    Path_file = files[i]
    new_path = Path_save + "Yearx/" + "DOYx/"
    if not os.path.isdir(new_path):
       os.mkdir(new_path) 
    break
```

Comment: Side note: use `for Path_file in files:` instead of using a range of indices.

Comment: Why is the `os.mkdir()` in your loop when it only ever will create a directory once, at most? Put it outside of the loop.

Comment: @Remmelzwaal, because Yearx and DOYx is in the loop.

Comment: Where? Those strings are constant. So is `Path_save`, defined outside the loop. `new_path` is the same every iteration.

Comment: @Remmelzwaal,
    file_basename = str(os.path.basename(Path_file)) 
    Date_filename = re.split(r'[_.]+', file_basename)
    Year = Date_filename[2]
    DOY = Date_filename[3]
    Yearx = str(Year)
    DOYx = str(DOY)
    Hour = Date_filename[4]

Comment: That is not in the code you posted. Besides, you would need to use `f'{Yearx}/' + f'{DOYx}/'` to get them to be variable. Even better, just use `new_path = os.path.join(Path_save, Yearx, DOYx)` so you don't run into these kinds of issues at all.

Comment: @Remmelzwaal,  thank you very much for your effort. It's still not working.

This is the response:
The system cannot find the path specified: 'I:/White_Bubble_2023/COSMIC_Renamed/2020/258/'

Comment: You will have to split up the `isdir()` checks for each new subdirectory you want to make, since the innermost directory doesn't have a parent so the directory cannot be found.

Comment: @Remmelzwaal, thanks
this worked for me.

Path(f'{Path_save}/{Yearx}/{DOYx}').mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

Comment: Didn't know `mkdir()` had a parents parameter. Good to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

os.mkdir(new_path)

Is how you create folders in Python. That technically answers your question as written. Well, ignoring the fact that you did not write a question mark at the end of the sentence.

But I want to be actually helpful instead of technically following the RAW. So I recommend adding debug outputs in situations like this. So you can see in which iteration and with which values it fails.

So for this example I recommend:
adding
print(new_path)

immediately after:
new_path = Path_save + "Yearx/" + "DOYx/"

That way you get a better understanding of when and why it fails.

Comment: You could also edit the question if you don't quite understand my problem. I have tried your answer, it printed but still not creating the path.